# Triple boot mid-2012 MacBook Pro, rEFInd linux boots Windows?

Tags: linux, grub, refind

My MacBook Pro has two internal hard drives, and they're now laid out like this:

- SSD

  - Mac HD
  - Bootcamp
- SATA

  - Storage (for Mac)
  - grub/bios/boot
  - swap
  - linux mint

During the Mint installer, when asked where to install GRUB, I selected /dev/sdb (the SATA drive). rEFInd correctly sees 3 OS'es, but if I choose either Windows (something like /dev/sda2) or Mint (/dev/sdb4 ?) they both boot Windows.

Not sure what I did wrong, or how to fix it. Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

Edit - when it boots windows (after selecting Linux in rEFInd) it doesn't even show grub. So I'm imagining I installed grub wrong. Hrm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the cause was, but after many reinstalls, I eventually noticed that when booting from the Mint installer DVD, rEFInd was offering a few different boot options from the DVD. One of them was an EFI boot. Selecting this option worked.

I instructed the installer to install Mint to /dev/sdb4, and GRUB to the same partition. Not sure what *ended up happening*, as I still have no visibility of GRUB. Now when I boot my MacBook, it boots directly into Mint. If I hold Alt (Option) down at boot, the OS X boot-selector allows me to select between OS X, Windows, and Windows (which is actually Mint).

Up and running -- thanks!